# Locally working selenium browser download file automation code does not work in aws linux server?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm  trying to automate the downloading and processing of a certain csv file from a clients dashboard. The below code works on my local, in both headless and headed mode. I'm also able to manually download the file locally. However, I'm not able download the file when I run the code on my aws linux server. The file is large and needs to be regularly imported, hence I need to put this into a working cron in my server. Can anyone please look through this code and tell me what I should do to download the file in my server?

Thanks

/code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re, unicodedata, time, datetime, arrow
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
print "### {} ###".format(arrow.now())
def browser_init(page_load_timeout=15):
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/Users/deepak/Desktop/Adlmnt/"}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

    webdriver_paths = [
    "/Users/deepak/Downloads/chromedriver_Mac2",
    "/feed_log/pyenv/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver_3"
    ]

    download_dir = [
    "/Users/deepak/Desktop/Adlmnt/Ibv/ibv/discovery/working/Cdt_crawl/data",
    "/feed_log/pyenv/selenium/webdriver/chrome/downloads/"
    ]

    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : download_dir}
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

    dpath = ''
    ## find webdriver, open browser instance
    for path_ in webdriver_paths:
        try:
            browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_, chrome_options=chromeOptions, service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])
            browser.set_page_load_timeout(page_load_timeout)
            browser.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
            #browser.set_window_size(300, 500)
            browser.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
            dpath = download_dir[webdriver_paths.index(path_)]
            params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior':
            'allow', 'downloadPath': dpath}}
            browser.execute("send_command", params)
            print path_
            print dpath
            browse = browser
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print "could not open browser: ", e
            browse = None
            continue

    print browse
    return browse, dpath


## login cdt
def cdt_init(browser,login_timeout=5):
    browser.get("https://dashboard.cdt.com/#/login")
    try:
        user = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))
    finally:
        user.send_keys("user_name")
        browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("pass_word")
        browser.find_element_by_name("password").submit()
    print "timing out for login"
    time.sleep(login_timeout)
    return browser

def cdt_labs(browser,dpath='/feed_log/pyenv/selenium/webdriver/chrome/downloads/', labs=None,dowload_timeout=15):
    try:
        labs = labs.format(arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        print "fetching link: ", labs
        loaded = False
        while not loaded:
            try:
                browser.get(labs)
                loaded = True
            except Exception as e:
                print "could not load labs: ",e
                loaded = False
                print "retrying in a few moments..."
                time.sleep(5)
        print arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        print browser.current_url

        while labs!=browser.current_url:
            browser.get(labs)
            print "fetching link: ", labs
            print "current  link: ", browser.current_url
            time.sleep(3)
        print "cdt labs opened"

        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='ng-scope']")))
        finally:
            try:
                time.sleep(3)
                print element
                print "clicking on export"
                element.click()
                try:
                    c = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']")))
                    print c
                    print "waited for export, waited for export all"
                finally:
                    try:
                        c.click()
                    except:
                        browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']")[0].click()
                        print "wait for export all, not successful:", browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']")
                #c = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']");
                #print c
                #print "clicking on export all data"
                #c.click()
                #time.sleep(dowload_timeout)
            except:
                print "clicking on export"
                time.sleep(3)
                browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='ng-scope']")[0].click()
                print "wait for export not successful: ", browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='ng-scope']")
                print "clicking on export all data"
                try:
                    c = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']")))
                    print c, "wait for export all successful"
                finally:
                    try:
                        c.click()
                    except:
                        print "wait for export all unsuccessful", browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']")
                        browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='labs-item-select ng-binding']")[0].click()

        time.sleep(dowload_timeout)
        ## checking/waiting for file to be downloaded
        dirName = dpath
        downloaded = False
        download_d_checks = 6
        while ((not downloaded) and (download_d_checks > 0)):
            if not (os.path.exists(dirName) and os.path.isdir(dirName)):
                print("Given Directory doesn't exists")
                browser.quit()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                if not os.listdir(dirName):
                    print("Directory is empty")
                    print "waiting a few moments..."
                    download_d_checks -= 1
                    time.sleep(5)
                    #browser.quit()
                    #sys.exit()
                else:
                    downloaded = True
                    print("Directory is not empty")
                    file_ = os.listdir(dirName)[0]
                    print file_
                    print type(file_)
                    data = pd.read_csv(dirName+file_)
                    os.remove(dirName+file_)
                    print data.head(5)

        ## print browser.html
        #print browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;")
        return browser, True

    except Exception as e:
        print "Error: ", e
        raise e
        #browser.quit()
        return browser, False

browser,dpath = browser_init(page_load_timeout=15)
print "browser init done"
browser = cdt_init(browser)
print "cdt init done"
browser, download_status = cdt_labs(browser,dpath=dpath,labs="https://dashboard.cdt.com/#/reports/cdt-labs/{}/{}/0/6&3&7&15/r=desc/0",dowload_timeout=30)

if download_status:
    print "file downloaded"
else:
    print "file did not download"

browser.quit()
print arrow.now()
```

I get the following output while running on my server:

```
### 2018-05-27T13:57:41.028244+00:00 ###
could not open browser:  Message: 'chromedriver_Mac2' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

/feed_log/pyenv/selenium/webdriver/chrome/chromedriver_3
/feed_log/pyenv/selenium/webdriver/chrome/downloads/
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="4af93975ddc008717bd40286c930461a")>
browser init done
timing out for login
cdt init done
fetching link:  https://dashboard.cdt.com/#/reports/cdt-labs/2018-05-27/2018-05-27/0/6&3&7&15/r=desc/0
could not load labs:  Message: timeout
  (Session info: headless chrome=64.0.3282.167)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 3.13.0-87-generic x86_64)

retrying in a few moments...
2018-05-27
https://dashboard.cdt.com/#/reports/cdt-labs/2018-05-27/2018-05-27/0/6&3&7&15/r=desc/0
cdt labs opened
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4af93975ddc008717bd40286c930461a", element="0.8633500363426354-1")>
clicking on export
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4af93975ddc008717bd40286c930461a", element="0.8633500363426354-2")>
waited for export, waited for export all
Directory is empty
waiting a few moments...
Directory is empty
waiting a few moments...
Directory is empty
waiting a few moments...
Directory is empty
waiting a few moments...
Directory is empty
waiting a few moments...
Directory is empty
waiting a few moments...
file downloaded
2018-05-27T13:59:14.039865+00:00
```

python version: Python 2.7.6

I get the message at the end as file downloaded- but dont be confused, it didn't download, thats just a message I kept to show the code fully executed. the download directory remains empty regardless of how much timeout I add. PS: I'm not sure if it matters but I've masked the name of url/client.

What could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and i solved it giving writing permisions to download directory.

```
download_default_directory = '/path/to/download_dir'
os.chmod(download_default_directory, 0777) # 0666 must be enought
```